# Running script after reboot does not work

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, linux, python-3

I have a simple script will runs a loop that reads off temp data in the console from a sensor and then writes it to a file. I would like to make sure that this script starts running right after my pi is rebooted. To keep the data flowing after a power outage and etc. I am running on Pi 3, Debian v9.11, Raspbian GNU/Linux 9, Python 3. Below is what I am using:

I decided to go for **rc.local** method since I am planning to run this pi in headless mode after I get everything tested. Right before the exit 0 line of the file I have the following line of code:

```
sudo python /home/pi/pi_projects/temp/temp.py &
```

When I reboot the script does not start and I have to run it manually. After some research, I saw that some folks resolved this by changing the script file permissions to 755. I have tried that as well but same result.

Below is the script I am trying to run on reboot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT as DHT
import lcddriver
import time
from datetime import datetime, date
import csv
import sys
import os


sensor = DHT.DHT11
pin = 17
path = 'data.csv'
lcd = lcddriver.lcd()
lcd.lcd_clear()


def get_time_now():     # get system time
    return datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')


def get_date():     # get system time
    return date.today()


def measure_pi_temp():
    temp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()
    temp = temp.replace("temp=","")
    temp = temp.replace("'C","")
    return (float(temp) * 9/5.0 + 32)


def loop():
    while (True):
        humidity, temperature = DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
        #if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        if humidity is not None and humidity < 101:
            humidity = round(humidity, 2)
            temperature = round((temperature * 9/5.0 + 32), 2)
            print('Pi Temp: {4:0.1f}F Room Temp: {0:0.1f}F Humidity: {1:0.1f}% Time: {2} Date: {3}'.format(temperature, humidity, get_time_now(), get_date(), measure_pi_temp()))
            lcd.lcd_display_string('T:' + str(temperature) + 'F ' + 'H:' + str(humidity) + '%', 1)
            lcd.lcd_display_string('Time: ' + get_time_now(), 2)
        else:
            print('none')

        data = [measure_pi_temp(), temperature, humidity, get_time_now(), get_date()]

        with open(path, 'a') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(data)
        time.sleep(30)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Program is starting...')
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
        exit()
```

Comment: @joan would like to see the entire script. Wasn't sure if it was relevant since the script runs just fine. I can add it if that helps.

Comment: I expect it's a path type problem.  Perhaps see if it works when you add `@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/pi_projects/temp/temp.py` to your user crontab (`cron -e`) and reboot.

Comment: I could not install the gnome-schedule. Keep getting dpkg error no matter what I do so thats why I opted for this option.

Comment: Its saying cron: invalid option - - 'e'

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I meant `crontab -e`

Comment: @joan that got the cron working but after reboot it still doesn't work. Nothing is loading.

Comment: You should add some debug logging to the script so you can determine where/when things go wrong.  Note that using `sudo` in `rc.local` is at best pointless, it is run with root privileges at boot.

Comment: @joan Nope. Also, the path that starts with /user/bin/... doesn't seem to exist so I did realpath to confirm that the absolute path to the file is the one that stars with /hom/pi/.. and tried using that one but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

`rc.local` runs with an empty environment, so you need to use absolute paths of all commands that you call. Currently you execute `sudo` with `python /home/pi/pi_projects/temp/temp.py` as arguments. Since you don't specify the full path of the executable you run (that is, `/usr/bin/sudo`), your command cannot be started.

Notably, `rc.local` is executed with root permissions, so you don't need to put `sudo` there at all. You should give your script as an argument to `/usr/bin/python` (note the full path).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this. Can you tell me exactly what I should add to the rc.local?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/pi_projects/temp/temp.py &`